# How to Extract m3u8 url of a webpage without Developers tool and Extension

Tags: m3u8, sniffer

I want a code in javascript or php to extract m3u8 url from a webpage .

Means When we load a webpage code will automatically fetch its m3u8 link and display it in a webpage.
If anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any information,

You can use PHP with curl to get response from page then trim tha data ( if ) m3u8 link is embeded or saved on page directly you can trim data accordingly and then echo "$url";

In case website loads m3u8 from api server or from different url after starting session . i.e site.com/link.php?name=video

You need to send request to site.com/link.php?name=video with proper header , user-agent and cookies if required (api keys)
Then you can decode the json data and display your link.

I